# Problem with deepreplay package: ValueError: Unable to create group (name already exists)

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, valueerror, h5py, keyerror

Recently I faced a problem when I used [deepreplay package](https://github.com/dvgodoy/deepreplay) as its Traceback follows:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-c3b5d8180301> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit(X, y, epochs=50, batch_size=16, callbacks=[replay])

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/deepreplay/callbacks.py in on_train_begin(self, logs)
     83         self.n_epochs = self.params['epochs']
     84 
---> 85         self.group = self.handler.create_group(self.group_name)
     86         self.group.attrs['samples'] = self.params['samples']
     87         self.group.attrs['batch_size'] = self.params['batch_size']

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/group.py in create_group(self, name, track_order)
     63             name, lcpl = self._e(name, lcpl=True)
     64             gcpl = Group._gcpl_crt_order if track_order else None
---> 65             gid = h5g.create(self.id, name, lcpl=lcpl, gcpl=gcpl)
     66             return Group(gid)
     67 

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py/h5g.pyx in h5py.h5g.create()

ValueError: Unable to create group (name already exists)
```

I shared the google colab [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nPWj8zF6M8jIhTYgVuT4wXy6GRCmSmLv?usp=sharing) which I could run on Aug 2, 2019, but now it threw out this `KeyError: 'samples'`   in 2021. Please check the notebook and feel free to run it for quick debugging.

Following is the configuration and package versions in google colab:

```
matplotlib==3.2.2
matplotlib-inline==0.1.3
matplotlib-venn==0.11.6
numpy==1.19.5
pandas==1.1.5
pandas-datareader==0.9.0
pandas-gbq==0.13.3
pandas-profiling==1.4.1
scikit-learn==1.0.1
scipy==1.4.1
seaborn==0.11.2
sklearn-pandas==1.8.0
Python 3.7.12
```

This is the full code:

```py
#!pip install deepreplay
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
#from keras.optimizers import SGD
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.initializers import glorot_normal, normal

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(input_dim=2,
                units=2,
                activation='sigmoid',
                kernel_initializer=glorot_normal(seed=42),
                name='hidden'))
model.add(Dense(units=1,
                activation='sigmoid',
                kernel_initializer=normal(seed=42),
                name='output'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=SGD(learning_rate=0.05), metrics=['acc'])

from deepreplay.callbacks import ReplayData
from deepreplay.datasets.parabola import load_data
from deepreplay.replay import Replay

X, y = load_data()

replay = ReplayData(X, y, filename='hyperparms_in_action.h5', group_name='part1')
model.fit(X, y, epochs=50, batch_size=16, callbacks=[replay])
```

I found the similar open issues [here](https://github.com/igormq/asr-study/issues/5) & [here](https://githubmemory.com/repo/igormq/asr-study/issues/6) related to saving model via hdf5 file.  I tried based on some suggestions [12195#](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12195#issuecomment-840962580) and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26811#issuecomment-568724236) to save the model with `tf` instead of `h5` in `replay_filename` which was unsuccessful.  There is lots of post in this regard in [SoF](https://www.google.com/search?q=ValueError:+Unable+to+create+group+(name+already+exists)+site:stackoverflow.com&rlz=1C1GCEA_enDE923DE923&sxsrf=AOaemvKE4wCUvSo4TPareI-jPST--osLWg:1638800977380&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjNuvSwsc_0AhWiSvEDHYI_DK0QrQIoBHoECAgQBQ&biw=2133&bih=1013&dpr=0.9)

Following the [Github issue](https://github.com/dvgodoy/deepreplay/issues/28), I tried and replaced following scripts to dynamically change the name when I run the cell:

```py
import datetime as dt
dtime = dt.time()
now = dt.datetime.now()
zeit = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print(f"Last update of notebook:{zeit}")

X, y = load_data()

#replay = ReplayData(X, y, filename='hyperparms_in_action.h5', group_name='part1')
replay = ReplayData(X, y, filename='hyperparms_in_action{{zeit}.h5', group_name=f'part1_{zeit}')
```

but still, those errors mentioned in the issue remain and couldn't figure out what's wrong when I run them in Google [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nPWj8zF6M8jIhTYgVuT4wXy6GRCmSmLv?usp=sharing) recently. Additionally, I checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69211778/valueerror-unable-to-create-group-name-already-exists-in-h5py) if the problem is  *"overwrite the data inside a given group contained in the `h5` file."

I also tried to debug line by line I get the following error if you check the notebook:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-2329c97991e2> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit(X, y, epochs=10, batch_size=16, callbacks=[replaydata])

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/deepreplay/callbacks.py in on_train_begin(self, logs)
     84 
     85         self.group = self.handler.create_group(self.group_name)
---> 86         self.group.attrs['samples'] = self.params['samples']
     87         self.group.attrs['batch_size'] = self.params['batch_size']
     88         self.group.attrs['n_batches'] = (self.params['samples'] + self.params['batch_size'] - 1) // \

KeyError: 'samples'
```

Any helps will be highly appreciated.